# Conditional branching in sed

Tags: sed

I have well a well-defined problem that seems like a good candidate for sed.

My input file contains either one of two tokens:

`[FILE]` or `[LINE]`

The structure looks like this:

```
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\build.xml
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\dataload-pom.xml
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\local.properties
    [LINE]:  [job.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.client.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [bill.report.toAddress=]
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\pom.xml
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\release.properties
    [LINE]:  [job.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.client.toAddress=]
```

The expected output would be:

```
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\local.properties
    [LINE]:  [job.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.client.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [bill.report.toAddress=]
[FILE]: C:\Users\user\git\release.properties
    [LINE]:  [job.mail.toAddress=]
    [LINE]:  [log.mail.client.toAddress=]
```

I only want to see filenames if they have lines associated with them.  I'm brand-spanking new to sed, and would like a complete understanding of what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another variant:

```
sed '/LINE/{H;x;:r;n;/LINE/br;x;d};h;d'
```

It keeps the last line all the time, and when it sees 'LINE, it displays the last line, then displays all following lines containing 'LINE, and the process repeats so recursively.

It works with any possible sed.

Comment: What's the colon syntax in the middle... I understand semicolons delimit commands, but I haven't seen the colon.

Comment: After the S(earch) command there is a separator character. Usually you can put it '/', but you can put any other character. For example, if the search expression contains '/' it is ugly to write s///. This is why sed allows any separator char. I use that char that I consider to look the nicest for the given situation.

Comment: Quote from the `info sed` [the man of sed is incomplete]:

The syntax of the `s` (as in substitute) command is
`s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS`.  The `/` characters may be uniformly
replaced by any other single character within any given `s` command.

Comment: ah, I am sorry :) . The colons there insert a label 'r' (from 'repeat') to jump to :). I thought that you ask about the colons of 'search' -- I did not use search directly here, but match via //. :))

Comment: Thanks! I am learning sed and this answer really helped develop my understanding! Since you're clearly a guru, may I ask why you use "x" rather than "g", since in neither usage do you actually need the hold space back in the pattern space?

Comment: At the end of the loop I save the current line with `h` in ps. When the next line comes, I check that it contains `LINE`. If it contains, I get the line saved from ps (again with `x`), and loop until no line has LINE, and in this case I save next line in ps with `x`.

Comment: If you love sed, I wrote a sed compiler here http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2011-05/msg00745.html, but it is not finished. I wrote onlu the parser. If you are motivated, I can help you finish it.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/^\(\[FILE\]\).*\n\1/!P;D' file
```

Deletes multiple `[FILE]` lines retaining the last.